# What is the appropriate construct for stating that "A and B oppose each other's positions."?

Tags: grammar

For example, in a sentence that states "Person A and Person B reacted with terror at each others' views," is there a more formal way to phrase this? The current phrasing seems like an awkward way to convey that Person A reacted with terror at Person B's views, while Person B simultaneously reacted with terror at Person A's views.

EDIT:

I think I obfuscated my question in the initial post. I'm wondering if there is a more formal way to phrase that the opinions in question are each others? The current phrasing seems like an awkward way to convey that Person A is reacting to person B's opinions and person B is reacting to A's positions.

Comment: @StoneyB- I think *view* here is in the sense of *opinion/position/stance* on some set of issues.

Comment: @Jim hmmm ... looking at the Title question I think you're right. I'll kill my comment.

Comment: I wouldn't mind an example of this. I can easily imagine being _angered_ by someone's views, or _frustrated_ by someone's views, or _astonished_ by someone's views, but, outside the context of Jodie Foster's character in _Silence of the Lambs_, I'm having trouble imagining a scenario where opposing opinions struck "terror" in the hearts of those in disagreement (which is why I suggested something a bit more mild and generic in my answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might say “Persons A and B found each other’s views terrifying”, or perhaps with *[abhorrent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abhorrent#Adjective)* in place of terrifying, if you mean they each found the  other’s views *[detestable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/detestable#Adjective)* or *[repulsive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repulsive#Adjective)* or *[repugnant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/repugnant#Adjective)* rather than frightening.  Some of these words can be used in verb forms; *eg* “Persons A and B abhorred, detested, and [reviled](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/revile#Verb) each other’s views”. (*Reviled* of course does not mean they were frightened of  each other’s views, but that they roundly criticized or denigrated them.)

Comment: +1 for more synonyms. I phrased my question incorrectly at first, I think, because the repugnance or distaste for another's stance wasn't what I was trying to rephrase. I was wondering if there is a better way than "each others' views" that didn't use "each others'", since that sounded awkward to me for whatever reason. If it isn't awkward, I can happily stay with that.

Comment: @Ricardo, ok.  I naturally assumed that the clumsy phrasing you referred to was “reacted with terror at”.  If you want to avoid  “each others’” for whatever reason, you can use an “Each of A and B ... views of the other” form, as in *eg* “Each of A and B traduced the views of the other.”

Comment: Or something like "recoiled in horror at". By the way, shouldn't it be "each other's"? (Each only has one other...)

Comment: @Billy, you probably are right about others' vs other's; I edited answer.  Looks like a reason to prefer “Each of A and B ... views of the other” form.

Answer (score 2):

This may come across as too clinical, but how about:

> A and B held diametrically opposed views

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

> A and B are *at odds with* each other.

That phrase is more mild than reacting with “terror”, but it does imply a sharp and perhaps contentious disagreement.

If that's doesn't convey enough “terror” for you, than you could try:

> A and B were both *horrified* by (or *mortified* by) each other's viewpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the initial sentence that awkward. But *one another* sometimes feels slightly more elegant than *each other*:

> A and B reacted with terror to one another's views.

However, if the whole structure of the sentence is not what you want, the following type of structure is often seen and carries the more "formal" tone you may be looking for:

> A was as terrified by B's views as B was by A's.
>
> B's views terrified A as much as A's terrified B.

This might sound clumsy, but probably works better with the insertion of actual names: "Nick's views terrified Elizabeth as badly as hers terrified him."

Answer (score -1):

A and B reacted to one another’s views with mutual terror.